# When I enter a name in a form and that name already exists in a database, I want to give a message saying "This name already exists" using queries

Tags: html, sql, coldfusion

I'm a beginner so I Want to know how you can check if a name already exist in the database and give an alert or a message saying the name already exist in the database
but i don't want to use jquery or js just cf and the queries.

```
<cfif isDefined("Button")>
            <cfquery name='Insert' datasource='mysql'>
                INSERT INTO tbl_products_manager
                (Name)
                VALUES ('#name#')
            </cfquery>
            <cfinclude  template="pr.cfm">
        </cfif>
```

I want to know what i should write in the next cfquery or to add the message

Comment: I'm not sure how coldfusion works, but when the form is submitted, the submit handling could check the DB for the given name. If the name exists, return an error to the form that the name exists, otherwise insert the name and return success to the form the name was added, unless the next step goes elsewhere.

Comment: Do you acknowledge that more than one person can have the same name?  Also, to check if records exist, run a `select` query.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
<cfquery name='Insert' datasource='mysql' result='local.stResult'>     
INSERT INTO tbl_products_manager
(Name)
VALUES (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#name#" />)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbl_products_manager WHERE Name = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#name#" />)
</cfquery>
```

Then you can dump local.stResult and figure out the result value that has the modified record count. (Can't remember offhand.)  If the value is 0, you know it wasn't inserted.

As you indicate you are new to Coldfusion, please, please look up `<cfqueryparam>` and use it in every...single...query, every time.

The above is but one solution.  You can also do a separate query first.  Or you can have an identity (or MySQL equivalent) on the table and also get that in the stResult struct.  There are a myriad of ways.  Strenghten your sql-fu, and your CFML query/proc usage will get stronger, too!